# Plotly 3D plot annotations

Tags: python, annotations, plotly, label

I am trying to generate a random 3D scatter plot where each point has a label. How can I add these labels? I would like to add them inside the yellow box.

[image]

Comment: You can use a [hovertemplate](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate) to customize the text. Can you provide the code you have written so far to generate the plot, and what labels you would want to assign these points? I think you will be more likely to get an answer if you make your question a bit more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're specifically asking how to

> add them inside the yellow box

you're not really asking how to annotate a 3D chart, which you could otherwise do with [3D annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#3d-annotations), but really how to customize the hover info. If you're willing to use [`plotly.express`](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/), you can use `custom_data` in `px.scatter_3D()` to include information about a fourth variable not displayed in the scatterplot:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                        color='petal_length', size='petal_length', size_max=18,
                        symbol='species', opacity=0.7,
                        custom_data = ['category']
                   )

temp1 = fig.data[0].hovertemplate
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = temp1 + '<br>' + "Category: %{customdata[0]}")
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
category = {'setosa':'flower', 'versicolor': 'vegetable', 'virginica': 'not a flower'}
df['category'] = df['species'].map(category)
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                        color='petal_length', size='petal_length', size_max=18,
                        symbol='species', opacity=0.7,
                        custom_data = ['category']
                   )

temp1 = fig.data[0].hovertemplate
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = temp1 + '<br>' + "Category: %{customdata[0]}")

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example using [plotly.graph_objects](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter3d.html):

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# create a cube mesh, 5 x 5 x 5 points
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 5), np.linspace(-1, 1, 5), np.linspace(-1, 1, 5))
values = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)  # just a dummy value for each point

# create the plot
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x.flatten(),
            y=y.flatten(),
            z=z.flatten(),
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(size=5, color=values.flatten()),
            hovertext=[f"value={v:.3f}" for v in values.flatten()], # <--  hover text here
        )
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

[image]