# Plotly: How to add extra information to marker of 3D scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

What I'd like to do is adding each string info into only each balloon like below capture. But without showing them next to each plot because it looks messy when plots are many.

[image]

My data frame is below, I added info to each row as string.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

digits = datasets.load_digits()

X_reduced = TSNE(n_components=3, random_state=0).fit_transform(digits.data)

myinfo = ['ID' + str(i+1) for i in range(X_reduced.shape[0])]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X_reduced, columns=columns, dtype='float')

df['info'] = myinfo          ## <- This is what i want to show in a balloon.

print(df)

              a         b          c    info
0     18.150545 -1.938995   1.192057     ID1
1     -8.773806  2.475938 -10.885373     ID2
2      4.305762  5.132519  -7.347726     ID3
3      5.327038  7.438313   8.786077     ID4
4    -15.810744 -9.374986   0.310686     ID5
...         ...       ...        ...     ...
1792   1.192152 -0.850245  12.781646  ID1793
1793  14.183956 -3.544634  -1.009673  ID1794
1794  -0.907307  2.596647  -4.307703  ID1795
1795   1.608326  0.700724   9.267643  ID1796
1796   1.809730  5.428222  -1.771497  ID1797
```

What I tried is that I assigned the string info as **text='info'** of px.scatter_3d() as following code.

```py
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='a', y='b', z='c', color='a', size_max=6 , text='info', opacity=0.7)

fig.show()
```

Does someone know how to get rid of these info beside plots?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [Plotly 3D plot annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262505/plotly-3d-plot-annotations/68267109#68267109) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your setup, all you have to do is run:

```
fig.update_traces(mode = 'markers')
```

...or:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(mode = 'markers'))
```

This removes the strings associated with the markers, but retains the added information in the hoverlabel:

[image]

This approach lets you keep your call to `px.scatter_3d(..., text='info')` as it stands.

Another approach would be to edit the hoverinfo directly with a `custom_value` as described in the post [Plotly 3D plot annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262505/plotly-3d-plot-annotations/68267109#68267109)